# imageview resizing while dragging a image in layout in android

Tags: android, drag, android-imageview

I am creating an android application in which i need to drag imageview. i tried using layout params and its moving fine but when the image moves nearby right and bottom corner of device then imageview became resizing. i dont know why this happens. my code is below what i tried.

```
 if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                    drag=true;

                    if(drag){
                        int x=(int) (me.getRawX());
                        int y=(int) (me.getRawY());

    innerlayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(innerlayout.getLayoutParams().width, innerlayout.getLayoutParams().height));
                 LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) innerlayout.getLayoutParams();
                 params.leftMargin = x-25;
                 params.topMargin = y-75;
                innerlayout.setLayoutParams(params);
                                                        }

                }


                else if(me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)

                {
                    drag=false;


                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: try to move the image with respect to your image's center co-ordinates.

Comment: @user370305 can you please explain little more?

Answer (score 0):

look at this [Moving Images on the Screen with Android](http://obviam.net/index.php/moving-images-on-the-screen-with-androi/)

[How to use Multi-touch in Android 2: Part 6, Implementing the Pinch Zoom Gesture](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-6-implementing-the-pinch-zoom-gesture/1847)